# Visual Studio 2008 SP1 with GDR2 - DBMDL could not be created

Tags: visual-studio, linq-to-sql, database-project

I get the following dialog when I try to load any DB project in Visual Studio.

[image]

There is nothing else locking it, nor are the permissions on that specific folder restrictive.
This used to work, but I re-installed VS2008, then Sp1, a few hot fixes and GDR2.

Now, when I try to load any DB project, I get the dialog above.

When I open VS, I get the following dialog; it's different, but message is the same..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check locks on files by using process explorer: 
http://windowsxp.mvps.org/processlock.htm

You can download process explorer here: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Answer (score 2):

Try opening Visual Studio as Administrator.